# Wrong char index in string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, indexing

I'm making a sudoku solver, and I ran into some problems I cannot solve...
The idea was to make a string array which is the sudoku board. So I have two for loops which passes two numbers in a method, one x and y to till which sudoku tile I'm on.
In this getPossibilitis method I add nine numbers in a list and when removes numbers if the string has the same number in the list.
This will leave me with all the Possibilitis. If only one possibiliti comes back, I insert this number in a StringBuilder which updates the sudoku board. The problem is that, when I pass in a number it check is the position is a number or not, if it is a number the method returns 0. But when I pass in x = 0 y = 3 it couts this as a seven, when it should be a 8, and when x = 0 y = 5 it counts a as "." which is a empty space. Why does this happen? Why does the 8 disappear?

```
string[] board = { "6..874.1.",
                          "..9.36...",
                          "...19.8..",
                          "7946.....",
                          "..1.894..",
                          "...41..69",
                          ".7..5..9.",
                          ".539.79..",
                          "9.2.61.47" };
```

```
private void solve()
{
  bool noMoves = false;
  while ( noMoves == false )
  {
    for ( int row = 0; row < 9; row++ )
    {
      for ( int line = 0; line < 9; line++ )
      {

        if ( row == 0 && line == 2 )
        {

        }
        List<string> Possibilitis = getPossibilitis(row, line);
        if ( board[Convert.ToInt32(row)][line] == '.' )
        {
          // 0,2
          if ( Possibilitis.Count == 1 )
          {
            string changeLine = board[row];
            StringBuilder changeIndex = new StringBuilder(changeLine);
            changeIndex.Remove(line, line);
            changeIndex.Insert(line, Possibilitis[0]);
            board[row] = changeIndex.ToString();
            //noMoves = true;

          }

        }
        if ( Possibilitis.Count == 0 ) { manyTimes++; }
        if ( manyTimes == 200 ) { noMoves = true; }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
printBoard();
```

```
private List<string> getPossibilitis(int row, int num_in_poss)
{
  // If the possition is a number; return a list with 0 in it.
  List<string> takenNumber = new List<string>(amountOfNums);
  switch ( Convert.ToChar(board[row][num_in_poss]) )
  {
    case '1':
      return takenNumber;
      break;
    case '2':
      return takenNumber;
      break;
    case '3':
      return takenNumber;
      break;
    case '4':
      return takenNumber;
      break;
    case '5':
      return takenNumber;
      break;
    case '6':
      return takenNumber;
      break;
    case '7':
      return takenNumber;
      break;
    case '8':
      return takenNumber;
      break;
    case '9':
      return takenNumber;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using strings for this? It makes the solution more complex and less performant and introduces the potential for problems such as you are describing.

Comment: *if I pass in x = 0 y = 3 it couts this as a seven, when it should be a 8* No, based on your code example, it should be a seven. I think you are mixing up *x* and *y*.

Comment: You may be thinking of "item #3", but the code is using "index #3", which is item #4, since arrays are zero-based.